# Use of FrameworkElement.FindResource("myResource") in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

Following MVVM, I have an object persisted with the existence of a UI Window, object defined in XAML.  This object represents the ModelView so it contains the controls which can modify the model.  I am finding myself calling `FrameworkElement.FindResource("myResource")` for every user control.  What is the proper way to grab the instance of this object?

XAML:

```xml
<p:MyModelView x:Key="modelView" />
```

CodeBehind:

```cs
//for every control I call:
public void SomeEventHandler(object _sender, EventArgs _someEventArgs) {
    MyModelView repeatedCode= this.FindResource("modelView")
    repeatedCode.DoSomeModificationRelatedToControl(args[] someArgs);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't sound like MVVM, can you show a concrete example?

Comment: All communication is between the View and the ModelView, why do you think it doesn't sound like MVVM?  The above code follows [MVVM QuickStart from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430869(v=PandP.40).aspx).

Comment: Why you creating instance of MyModelView in View and adding it to Resources, Why you cant have directly instance of it in .cs class where your the above eventhandler is , Atleast in that case you wont have to find it in Resources again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need your ViewModel a lot of places in your View code-behind, create and keep the ViewModel in a variable in the code-behind instead of creating it as a resource in your Xaml. For example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private MainViewModel _vm;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _vm = new MainViewModel()
        {
            Name = "MyViewModel",
            ...
        };
        this.DataContext = _vm;
    }
```

That last line is important - by making the ViewModel the View's DataContext, you can bind to it in Xaml like normal.

Now, your event handlers get at least a line or two shorter:

```
public void SomeEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs someEventArgs)
{
    _vm.DoSomeModificationRelatedToControl(someArgs);
}
```